# Integrating PayPal in PHP code

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am finding my way out, integrating PayPal with PHP.
But I have one question left. When reading this document:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/
PayPal recommends that we use:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
```

in order to to acknowledge receipt of the notification.

But in every tutorial I can find on the net, I see no trace of this.

Does that mean that it is after all not so important?
Or otherwise where should one include this line?

Thanks for any tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming everything else is properly set up on the webserver etc., a `200 OK` response is the default when PHP outputs a response. There's no need to explicitly set that header.

Comment: OK. In other words, this is just happening and I do not need to add anything in the code for that?

Comment: @Michel Typically, yes, unless you've gone and done something odd.

Comment: Thanks a lot then.